# Classical probability-exercise:

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that a random experiment has as its sample space the set of pairs of numbers $(x, y)$ such that both $x$ and $y$ take values in the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots n\}$, and any of these points in the Cartesian plane is considered to occur with identical probability. Calculate the probability that, by performing the random experiment once, a point $(x, y)$ is obtained:

The subsection with which I am confused is:

$d)$ such that $|x-y|\leq 1$

With the given condition, it follows that $-1\leq x-y\leq 1$ or $y-1\leq x\leq y+1$. It is difficult for me to count the points that meet the condition.

Comment: Hint: For each value of $y$, how many values can $x$ take? Remember here to also think about the edge cases where $y$ is very small or large. And I highly recommend to draw the grid for some relatively small $n$ to see the points visually and help formulate or confirm your hypothesis

Comment: The possibilities here in dictionary order are... $(1,1),(1,2),\underbrace{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)},\underbrace{(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)},\dots,\underbrace{(k,k-1),(k,k),(k,k+1)},\dots,(n,n-1),(n,n)$

Comment: Be sure to be careful about edge cases where $n$ is small as well.  For $n=1$ or $n=2$ for instance there are no "middle numbers" that aren't on the boundary like for the case of $n\geq 3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering a $n \times n$ matrix, the favourable points are the $n$ on the diagonal plus the $(n-1)$ points on the two lines near the diagonal thus

$$\mathbb{P}[|X-Y|\leq 1]=\frac{n+2(n-1)}{n^2}$$

$n\geq 2$

Comment: This is correct for $n=1$ as well

Comment: @samuel: you're right. Thanks